# 75 gb of files in iMovie but no files showing up

Tags: macos, imac, imovie

I have 75gb of storage used in iMovie but there are no files showing up there, How do I find these files?

Comment: Where is "in there"? What is telling you there is 75GB of space used?

Comment: The computer crashed when working on a video project and the file icons disappeared. I had a couple of smaller projects that were still there so I finished those and deleted all the related files hoping that the ones I was missing would show up. When nothing came through and the iMovie library icon still showed content i was confident that the files must still be there but there addresses were disconnected or deleted. Hope how I explained it makes sense - it's not the usual problem with just misplaced video files.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a "rubbish bin" like in iPhoto, you've got to get the bin empty to make actual room.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the iMove Library file > Show Package Contents.

Be aware that you're not really supposed to play around in there, you're supposed to let iMovie handle it.